# How to tell if match data is empty?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsdata, game-center

I'm writing a turn based iOS game and right now I am having issues detecting when match data is empty. This is my function to load match data:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) loadMatchData
{
    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
     {
         if (matches)
         {
             currentGames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (int i = 0; i < matches.count; i++)
             {
                 [(GKTurnBasedMatch*)matches[i] loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error)
                  {
                      if (matchData != nil)
                      {
                          Game* game = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];
                          [currentGames addObject:game];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Game* game = [[Game alloc] init];
                          [currentGames addObject:game];
                          game.activePlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
                      }
                  }];
             }
         }
     }];

    return currentGames;
}
```

Unfortunately, matchData != nil doesn't seem to work, and neither does:

```
[matchData isEqualToData:[NSData alloc]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !matchData  || (matchData.length==0) )
```